# List azure containers with specific name type using Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to list a bunch of azure containers that have a specific name type - they are all called cycling-asset-group-x where x is a number or a letter e.g. cycling-asset-group-a, cycling-asset-group-1, cycling-asset-group-b, cycling-asset-group-2.

I only want to print the containers with a **number** in the suffix i.e. cycling-asset-group-1, cycling-asset-group-2 etc

How can I do this? Here's where I am up to so far:

```
account_name   = 'name'
account_key    = 'key'

# connect to the storage account 
blob_service   = BaseBlobService(account_name = account_name, account_key = account_key)
prefix_input_container = 'cycling-asset-group-'

# get a list of the containers - I think it's something like this...? 
cycling_containers = blob_service.list_containers("%s%d" % (prefix_input_container,...)) 

for c in cycling_containers:
    contname = c.name
    print(contname)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just pass your `prefix_input_container` value to the parameter `prefix` of the method `list_containers` of `BaseBlobService`, as the code below. Please see the API reference [`BaseBlobService.list_containers`](https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/ref/azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.html#azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.BaseBlobService.list_containers).

> list_containers(prefix=None, num_results=None, include_metadata=False, marker=None, timeout=None)[source]
>
> Parameters:
> **prefix** (str) – Filters the results to return only containers whose names begin with the specified prefix.

```
prefix_input_container = 'cycling-asset-group-'

cycling_containers = blob_service.list_containers(prefix=prefix_input_container) 

# Import regex module to filter the results
import re
re_expression = r"%s\d+$" % prefix_input_container
pattern = re.compile(re_expression)

# There are two ways.
# No.1 Create a generator from the generator of cycling_containers 
filtered_cycling_container_names = (c.name for c in cycling_containers if pattern.match(c.name))
for contname in filtered_cycling_container_names:
    print(contname)

# No.2 Create a name list
contnames = [c.name for c in cycling_containers if pattern.match(c.name)]
print(contnames)
```

Comment: Sorry Peter, I have updated the question to be clearer - there are multiple containers with this prefix, but with different suffixes

Comment: @Beansy I had updated my post, you can refer to my new codes.

Comment: @Beansy If my new answer has help you, could you mark it? Thanks.